# Laravel 5.3 codedge/laravel-fpdf Class Not found

Tags: laravel, pdf, fpdf

After updating composer with required packages and registering in config/app.php, I've tried laravel-fpdf in laravel 5.3,

```
    composer.json
   "require": {
       .....
      "codedge/laravel-fpdf": "^1.0"
     },

     providers
    Codedge\Fpdf\FpdfServiceProvider::class, 

    aliases
    'Fpdf' => Codedge\Fpdf\Facades\Fpdf::class,
```

simply in web.php routes like

Route::get('GeneratePdf', function (Codedge\Fpdf\Fpdf\FPDF $fpdf) {

```
$fpdf->AddPage();
$fpdf->SetFont('Courier', 'B', 18);
$fpdf->Cell(50, 25, 'Hello World!');
$fpdf->Output();
```

});
And I'm getting error
Class Codedge\Fpdf\Fpdf\FPDF does not exist

What could possibly be wrong ?

Comment: There was an error with autoloading the Fpdf class properly. This has been fixed in the latest version 1.21. Maybe you can update your installation - and please gimme a ping if sth. is not working. Happy to help!

Answer (score 3):

Try to remove service provider and alias from `config/app.php`, then run:

```
composer update
php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Codedge\Fpdf\FpdfServiceProvider" --tag=config
composer dumpauto
```

Then add service provider and alias back to `config/app.php`.

Answer (score 0):

The class name changed from Codedge\Fpdf\Fpdf\FPDF
to Codedge\Fpdf\Fpdf\Fpdf

The function name changed.
So you can update the previous to use Codedge\Fpdf\Fpdf\Fpdf;

Answer (score 0):

make sure you rename the file fpdf.php in src/Fpdf so that it start with a capital letter