# Class 'Codedge\Fpdf\FpdfServiceProvider' not found

Tags: laravel, fpdf

I'm trying to get FPDF to work with Laravel 5.5

I'm not sure if something has changed or what is going on.  I followed the advice in this thread first:

[How to generate fpdf?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47348486/how-to-generate-fpdf)

And then I followed the advice in this thread:

[Laravel 5.3 codedge/laravel-fpdf Class Not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40559827/laravel-5-3-codedge-laravel-fpdf-class-not-found)

But I'm still getting the error "Class 'Codedge\Fpdf\FpdfServiceProvider' not found"

Here is the important parts of my code:

From web.php:

```
Route::get('/workshops/registration/invoice/' function(){
    Fpdf::AddPage();
    Fpdf::SetFont('Arial', 'B', 18);
    Fpdf::Cell(50, 25, 'Hello World!');
    Fpdf::Output();
})->name('invoicePDF');
```

From my controller:

```
Redirect::route('invoicePDF');
```

From my config/app.php:

```
'providers' => [

     ....

     ....

    /*
     * Application Service Providers...
     */

     ....

     Codedge\Fpdf\FpdfServiceProvider::class,

     ....
],

'aliases' => [

     ....

     ....

    'Fpdf' => Codedge\Fpdf\Facades\Fpdf::class,

     ....

]
```

I've run

```
php artisan vendor:publish --provider='Codedge\Fpdf\FpdfServiceProvider' --tag=config"
```

both before and after adding to config/app.php, I've run both

```
composer dumpauto
```

and

```
composer dump-autoload
```

between, but nothing seems to be working.  I get the same "Class 'Codedge\Fpdf\FpdfServiceProvider' not found" error no matter what I do.

Am I missing something silly here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have everything set up right. You have verified the class exists right? This may be a good time to open a ticket on github with them as things look correct.